# Run C++ file with directory as argument? Using Bash instead?

Tags: c++, bash

I have a C++ file which takes an image as argument. I have a directory I need to do the script on. It looks like:

```
- parent
-- sub0
--- 0.pgm
--- 1.pgm
--- ...
-- sub1
--- 0.pgm
--- 1.pgm
--- ...
-- ...
```

`parent` contains 120 subfolders, and each subfolder contains 100-200 `.pgm` files. The C++ file takes a `.pgm` as argument.

Rather than running `file.cpp filename.pgm` thousands of times, is there a way to take a folder as argument in C++? I'd ideally like to either:

1. Call file.cpp on parent folder, it recursively works through the subfolders and files
2. Do it in Bash instead

With Bash, some pseudocode:

```
g++ -march=native -O2 file.cpp -o output
for $filename in folder
    ./output $filename
endfor
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Edit the program to take a directory instead of a file name?  Or make it to where it excepts both using flags?

Comment: How about a command line such as `find . -name "*.pgm" -exec ./output {} \;`?

Comment: @FredLarson note that the find command will execute itself sequentially. If there are a lot of files, a paralell aproach might be preferable

Comment: @Aserre: Which is also true of the OP's proposed script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` loops iterate over a list of strings, not over the contents of a directory. You need a glob to be expanded to the list of files you want.

```
shopt -s globstar
for filename in folder/**/*.pgm; do
   ./output "$filename"
done
```